# trouble installing apache.logging.log4j and slf4j on the build.sbt of my Scala Spark project

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, log4j, slf4j

I am having difficulties at setting the compatible libraries of the whole project. The build.sbt file is the following:

```
name := "YourProjectName"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.16"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation")

lazy val courseId = settingKey\[String\]("Course ID")
courseId := "e8VseYIYEeWxQQoymFg8zQ"

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.scala-sbt" % "sbt" % "1.1.6",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.4.1",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.4.1",
"org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.12.0", // Apache Commons Lang
"jline" % "jline" % "2.14.6"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.32",
"org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.17.1"
)
```

The error when I load the changes on sbt, and build and run the project on IntelliJ IDEA is as such:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(Lorg/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jMarkerFactory;)V
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JServiceProvider.initialize(SLF4JServiceProvider.java:54)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:183)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:170)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:455)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:441)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:390)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:416)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.<clinit>(JavaUtils.java:44)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigHelpers$.byteFromString(ConfigBuilder.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigBuilder.$anonfun$bytesConf$1(ConfigBuilder.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigBuilder.$anonfun$bytesConf$1$adapted(ConfigBuilder.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder.$anonfun$transform$1(ConfigBuilder.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder.createWithDefault(ConfigBuilder.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:378)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<init>(SparkConf.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<clinit>(SparkConf.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.setAppName(SparkConf.scala:120)
    at wikipedia.WikipediaRanking$.<init>(WikipediaRanking.scala:15)
    at wikipedia.WikipediaRanking$.<clinit>(WikipediaRanking.scala)
    at wikipedia.WikipediaRanking.main(WikipediaRanking.scala)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Running sbt dependencyTree on cmd.exe launches a log like this:

```
C:\Users\Enrique>sbt dependencyTree
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\Enrique\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\Enrique\project
[info] Set current project to enrique (in build file:/C:/Users/Enrique/)
[error] Not a valid command: dependencyTree
[error] Not a valid project ID: dependencyTree
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: dependencyTree (similar: dependencyOverrides, sbtDependency, dependencyResolution)
[error] dependencyTree
[error]
```

The main code demonstrates a Spark application that performs language ranking based on Wikipedia articles. It utilizes RDDs for distributed processing and leverages Spark's parallel processing capabilities. It reads like this:

```
package wikipedia

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

case class WikipediaArticle(title: String, text: String)

object WikipediaRanking {

  val langs = List(
    "JavaScript", "Java", "PHP", "Python", "C#", "C++", "Ruby", "CSS",
    "Objective-C", "Perl", "Scala", "Haskell", "MATLAB", "Clojure", "Groovy")

  val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wikipedia").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
  sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
  // Hint: use a combination of `sc.textFile`, `WikipediaData.filePath` and `WikipediaData.parse`
  val wikiRdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle] = sc.textFile(WikipediaData.filePath).map(l => WikipediaData.parse(l)).cache()

  /** Returns the number of articles on which the language `lang` occurs.
    *  Hint1: consider using method `aggregate` on RDD[T].
    *  Hint2: should you count the "Java" language when you see "JavaScript"?
    *  Hint3: the only whitespaces are blanks " "
    *  Hint4: no need to search in the title :)
    */
  def occurrencesOfLang(lang: String, rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): Int = {
    rdd.aggregate(0)((sum, article) => sum + isFound(article, lang), _+_)
  }

  def isFound(article: WikipediaArticle, lang: String): Int = if(article.text.split(" ").contains(lang)) 1 else 0

  /* (1) Use `occurrencesOfLang` to compute the ranking of the languages
   *     (`val langs`) by determining the number of Wikipedia articles that
   *     mention each language at least once. Don't forget to sort the
   *     languages by their occurrence, in decreasing order!
   *
   *   Note: this operation is long-running. It can potentially run for
   *   several seconds.
   */
  def rankLangs(langs: List[String], rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): List[(String, Int)] = {
    val ranks = langs.map(lang => (lang, occurrencesOfLang(lang, rdd)))
    //for{ lang <- langs; occ = occurrencesOfLang(lang, rdd) if occ != 0} yield (lang, occ)
    ranks.sortBy(_._2).reverse
  }

  /* Compute an inverted index of the set of articles, mapping each language
     * to the Wikipedia pages in which it occurs.
     */
  def makeIndex(langs: List[String], rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): RDD[(String, Iterable[WikipediaArticle])] = {
    val list = rdd.flatMap(article => for( lang <- langs if isFound(article, lang) == 1) yield (lang, article))
    list.groupByKey()
  }

  /* (2) Compute the language ranking again, but now using the inverted index. Can you notice
   *     a performance improvement?
   *
   *   Note: this operation is long-running. It can potentially run for
   *   several seconds.
   */
  def rankLangsUsingIndex(index: RDD[(String, Iterable[WikipediaArticle])]): List[(String, Int)] = {
    val ranks = index.mapValues(_.size).collect().toList.sortBy(-_._2)
    ranks
  }


  /* (3) Use `reduceByKey` so that the computation of the index and the ranking are combined.
   *     Can you notice an improvement in performance compared to measuring *both* the computation of the index
   *     and the computation of the ranking? If so, can you think of a reason?
   *
   *   Note: this operation is long-running. It can potentially run for
   *   several seconds.
   */
  def rankLangsReduceByKey(langs: List[String], rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): List[(String, Int)] = {
    val list = rdd.flatMap(article => for( lang <- langs if isFound(article, lang) == 1) yield (lang, 1))
    list.reduceByKey(_+_).collect().toList.sortBy(_._2).reverse
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    /* Languages ranked according to (1) */
    val langsRanked: List[(String, Int)] = timed("Part 1: naive ranking", rankLangs(langs, wikiRdd))
    langsRanked.foreach(println)

    /* An inverted index mapping languages to wikipedia pages on which they appear */
    def index: RDD[(String, Iterable[WikipediaArticle])] = makeIndex(langs, wikiRdd)

    /* Languages ranked according to (2), using the inverted index */
    val langsRanked2: List[(String, Int)] = timed("Part 2: ranking using inverted index", rankLangsUsingIndex(index))
    langsRanked2.foreach(println)

    /* Languages ranked according to (3) */
    val langsRanked3: List[(String, Int)] = timed("Part 3: ranking using reduceByKey", rankLangsReduceByKey(langs, wikiRdd))
    langsRanked3.foreach(println)

    /* Output the speed of each ranking */
    println(timing)
    sc.stop()
  }

  val timing = new StringBuffer
  def timed[T](label: String, code: => T): T = {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result = code
    val stop = System.currentTimeMillis()
    timing.append(s"Processing $label took ${stop - start} ms.\n")
    result
  }
}
```

I tried to look up in google what the compatible versions of log4j and slf4j are. Apart from that, I tried to click on the "Coursera_Scala_Spark" line for the full sbt error log details, and also prompted "sbt dependencyTree" to check the dependencies structure. I also entered this webpage ( https://index.scala-lang.org/apache/logging-log4j-scala ), but the solution doesn't seem to suit my project compilation.

Edit 1: I changed the log4j to a newer version, and removed the slf4j dependecies for being redundant. But still, the project can't run and the error log keeps asking for slf4j dependencies.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.15.0",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.15.0"
)
```

Comment: Sounds like you have an old SBT version. You can add the dependency tree plugin in the plugins.sbt file to be a le to use it.

Comment: Also you'll have to decide if you want to write logs with slf4j or log4j 2. Slf4j can forward to log4j or another lib. Log4j 2 can forward to slf4j which itself forward to another lib. Or you can use only log4j 2.

Comment: Thank you!!! I left the dependencies for log4j. Nevertheless, after "sbt clean", "sbt update", "sbt run" and running the project, I obtain an error log that starts with {Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>}

Comment: Another doubt: which sbt version would you recommend me to install? Scala 2.12.16 and Spark 3.4.1 are recent and stable versions?

Comment: Spark runtime will provide some libraries like slf4j probably. And thus Spark code expects slf4j to be available. So you probably don't have the choice to have slf4j but then you need to check for conflicts and make sure all libraries version are consistent.

Comment: SBT doesn't matter, use the latest 1.9.1. Spark 3.4 is the latest I think, so it's good. And Scala 2.12, you don't have much choice as you're using Spark, not yet compatible Scala 2.13 (or is it?).

Comment: @GaëlJ in this case `sbt` is the problem because it is used as a dependency library (don't know why). Just removing it would fix the problem

Comment: Was referring to the SBT version of the build. Didn't notice it was also a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the following libraries:

| library | version | released |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [sbt](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/sbt) | [1.1.6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.1.6) | `May 28, 2018` |
| [spark-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.12) | [3.4.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.12/3.4.1) | `June 23, 2023` |
| [spark-sql](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.12) | [3.4.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.12/3.4.1) | `June 23, 2023` |

As you can see, the version selected for `spark` is 5 years away from the one selected for `sbt`.

Each library, has different dependencies

- [sbt 1.1.6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.1.6)

  - [sbt main 1.1.6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/main_2.12/1.1.6)

    - [log4j-api 2.8.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.8.1)
    - [log4j-core 2.8.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1)
    - [log4j-slf4j-impl 2.8.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.8.1)
- [spark-core 3.4.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.12/3.4.1)

  - [log4j-api 2.19.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.19.0)
  - [log4j-core 2.19.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.19.0)
  - [log4j-slf4j-impl 2.19.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.19.0)

Again we have two version libraries with 5 years from one release to the other one.

It is supposed that if you follow [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/)

> Given a version number `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH`, increment the:
>
> 1. `MAJOR` version when you make incompatible API changes
> 2. `MINOR` version when you add functionality in a backward compatible manner
> 3. `PATCH` version when you make backward compatible bug fixes
>    Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.

and both libs are using `log4j 2.x.y`, selecting the higher one should work, but it could be that they are not [binary compatible](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/binary-compatibility-for-library-authors.html). I guess this is the case.

What I'm wondering if you really need `sbt` as a dependency library. If you remove it, the project will be able to compile.

You can try upgrade and downgrade `sbt` and `spark` and see if some combination of version between them works. Due to I don't know anything about your project, I can't suggest just remove sbt from your dependencies because I'm not sure if you are using something from sbt or why you added that dependency.

Sbt, depends on **scala 2.12**, so upgrading to **scala 2.13** could bring more problems.

I just tried quickly the following combinations in my local and I got these errors

- sbt 1.9.1
- spark-core 3.4.1

```
[error]     * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.12:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
[error]         +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.12:3.4.1         (depends on 2.1.1)
[error]         +- org.scala-sbt:zinc-compile-core_2.12:1.9.2         (depends on 1.1.2)
```

- sbt 1.8.3
- spark-core 3.4.1

```
[error]     * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.12:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
[error]         +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.12:3.4.1         (depends on 2.1.1)
[error]         +- org.scala-sbt:zinc-compile-core_2.12:1.8.1         (depends on 1.1.2)
```

- sbt 1.7.3
- spark-core 3.4.1

```
[error]     * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:2.1.0 (early-semver) is selected over {1.3.0, 1.2.0, 1.0.6}
[error]         +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:3.4.1             (depends on 2.1.0)
[error]         +- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.17              (depends on 2.1.0)
[error]         +- org.scala-sbt:testing_2.12:1.7.3                   (depends on 1.3.0)
[error]         +- org.scala-sbt:sbinary_2.12:0.5.1                   (depends on 1.0.6)
[error]         +- org.scala-sbt:main_2.12:1.7.3                      (depends on 1.3.0)
[error]         +- org.scala-sbt:librarymanagement-core_2.12:1.7.1    (depends on 1.2.0)
[error]         +- io.get-coursier:lm-coursier-shaded_2.12:2.0.12     (depends on 1.3.0)
```

---

related with the error you got when [sbt dependencyTree](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/sbt-dependency-tree) was executed, remember that before `sbt 1.4` you have to add the plugin in the `project/plugins.sbt` file like this

```scala
addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.10.0-RC1")
```

since `sbt 1.4`, you have to [add the plugin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-1.4-Release-Notes.html#sbt-dependency-graph+is+in-sourced) but with the following line

```scala
addDependencyTreePlugin
```

Once you do that, you will be able to execute the command